# JavaFX How to change css for an HBox

Tags: java, css, javafx, background-image

I wanna change the background image for the different levels i got:
This is my Methode to set the BackgroundImage while using css:

```
public void setBackgroundImage(HBox group, String ebene) {
        switch (ebene) {
            case "air": {
                String air_img = GrafikManager.class.getResource("/obkclient/img/Himmelsschlacht.jpg").toExternalForm();
                group.getStyleClass().removeAll(); //also tried with getStylsheets()
                group.setStyle("-fx-background-image: url('" + air_img + "');\n"
                        + "-fx-background-size: 1024, 768;\n"
                        + "-fx-background-repeat: stretch;\n"
                );
                break;
            }
            case "sub": {
                String sub_img = GrafikManager.class.getResource("/obkclient/img/Unterwasserschlacht.jpg").toExternalForm();
                group.getStyleClass().removeAll();
                group.setStyle("-fx-background-image: url('" + sub_img + "');\n"
                        + "-fx-background-size: 1024, 768;\n"
                        + "-fx-background-repeat: stretch;\n"
                );
                break;
            }
            default: {
                String image = GrafikManager.class.getResource("/obkclient/img/Seeschlacht.jpg").toExternalForm();
                group.getStyleClass().removeAll();
                group.setStyle("-fx-background-image: url('" + image + "');\n"
                        + "-fx-background-size: 1024, 768;\n"
                        + "-fx-background-repeat: stretch;\n"
                );
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

But if i start i only see the default BackgroundImage.
I'm using this Methode in following Context:

```
public SubScene buildFieldBackground(Scene scene){
        PerspectiveCamera subSceneFieldCamera = new PerspectiveCamera(false);
        scene.setCamera(subSceneFieldCamera);
        HBox subSceneGroup2 = new HBox();
        setBackgroundImage(subSceneGroup2, currentEbene);
        subSceneGroup2.setPadding(new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0));
        SubScene subScene2 = new SubScene(subSceneGroup2, 1024, 768);
        subScene2.setLayoutX(100);
        subScene2.setLayoutY(100);

        return subScene2;
    }
```

and the CurrentEbene can get following stats (setting by an other Methode): "air", "sea", "sub"

Where is the mistake i dont find, yet. Please help.

Comment: Note that `group.getStyleClass().removeAll();` doesn't do anything: you probably mean `group.getStyleClass().clear();`, though I don't think it will make any difference. Can you clarify; are you getting the image from the `default` case in your `switch` (i.e. the image in `Seeschlacht.jpg`)? If so, put a `System.out.println(ebene);` in to check what's being passed.

Comment: At the beginn i set currentEbene = "sea".
So i think the default case would get first.

Comment: I get the solution! i have a thread-exception before i set the background. i can't post the right code cause i havent enough points.
But if i reach them i will update my solution!

Answer (score 2):

I would actually recommend using an external style sheet for this, and manipulating the style class based on your "level" variable. You can do:

```
public void setBackgroundImage(HBox group, String ebene) {
    ObservableList<String> styleClass = group.getStyleClass();
    styleClass.setAll("hbox-group", ebene);
}


public SubScene buildFieldBackground(Scene scene){
        PerspectiveCamera subSceneFieldCamera = new PerspectiveCamera(false);
        scene.setCamera(subSceneFieldCamera);
        HBox subSceneGroup2 = new HBox();

        subSceneGroup2.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("subscene.css").toExternalForm());

        setBackgroundImage(subSceneGroup2, currentEbene);
        subSceneGroup2.setPadding(new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0));
        SubScene subScene2 = new SubScene(subSceneGroup2, 1024, 768);
        subScene2.setLayoutX(100);
        subScene2.setLayoutY(100);


        return subScene2;
    }
```

and then

subscene.css:

```
.hbox-group {
    -fx-background-size: 1024, 768;
    -fx-background-repeat: stretch;
    -fx-background-image: url('/obkclient/img/Seeschlacht.jpg') ;
}
.air {
    -fx-background-image: url('/obkclient/img/Himmelsschlacht.jpg') ;
}
.sea {
    -fx-background-image: url('/obkclient/img/Unterwasserschlacht.jpg') ;
}
```